# Time taken increasing exponentially when comparing elements in vectors

Tags: c++, performance, vector, montecarlo

I have a piece of code that looks like this:

```
void MonteCarloRainbowOptionFunction::ValueInstrument()
{
    std::vector<MJArray> correlatedNormVariates = GetArraysOfCorrelatedGauassiansByBoxMuller(numberOfPaths, covMatrix); 
    std::vector<StatisticAllPaths> thesePathGatherers;
    for (unsigned long i = 0; i < S_vect.size(); i++)
    {
        StandardExcerciseOption thisOption(ThePayOffVect[i], TTM);
        StatisticAllPaths onePathGatherer;
        thesePathGatherers.push_back(onePathGatherer);
        OneStepMonteCarloValuation(thisOption, S_vect[i], impvol_vect[i], r, d_vect[i], numberOfPaths, correlatedNormVariates[i], thesePathGatherers[i]);
    }
    f = 0;
    for (unsigned long i = 0; i < numberOfPaths; i++)
    {       
        int count = 0;
        if (i % 2500 == 0)
        {
            count += 1;
            std::cout << i << " paths done" << "\n";
        }
        std::vector<double> outcomes;
        for (unsigned long j = 0; j < S_vect.size(); j++)
        {
            outcomes.push_back(thesePathGatherers[j].GetResultsSoFar()[0][i]);
        }
        switch (optionType)
        {
        case RainbowOptionType::best_of:
            f += *max_element(outcomes.begin(), outcomes.end());
            break;
        case RainbowOptionType::worst_of:
            f += *min_element(outcomes.begin(), outcomes.end());
            break;          
        default:
            throw std::runtime_error("Unsupported or unknown option type found in " + GetuniqueIdentifier()[0]);
            break;
        }   
    }
    f *= ((double)nominal/numberOfPaths);
    return;
}
```

In the first part (before the first "Time Check") I simulate a large amount of values which gets saved in the vectors (really in the first vector of a vector of vectors) thesePathGatherers through the function OneStepMonteCarloValuation.  Like so (the time taken to do this is minimal):

```
void OneStepMonteCarloValuation(const StandardExcerciseOption& TheOption, double Spot, double Vol, double r, double d, unsigned long NumberOfPaths, MJArray normVariates, StatisticsMC& gatherer)
{
    if (normVariates.size() != NumberOfPaths)
        throw("mismatched number of paths and normal variates");
    //Pre-calculate as much as possible
    double Expiry = TheOption.GetExpiry();
    double variance = Vol * Vol * Expiry;
    double rootVariance = sqrt(variance);
    double itoCorrection = -0.5 * variance;
    double movedSpot = Spot * exp((r-d) * Expiry + itoCorrection);
    double thisSpot;
    double discounting = exp(-r * Expiry);
    for (unsigned long i = 0; i < NumberOfPaths; i++)
    {
        thisSpot = movedSpot * exp(rootVariance * normVariates[i]);
        double thisPayoff = TheOption.OptionPayOff(thisSpot);
        gatherer.DumpOneResult(discounting * thisPayoff);
    }
    return;
}
```

And the gatherer it calls here is this class:

```
StatisticAllPaths::StatisticAllPaths(const unsigned long minimumNumberOfPaths) : PathsDone(0)
{
    ResultList.reserve(minimumNumberOfPaths);
}

void StatisticAllPaths::DumpOneResult(double result)
{
    ResultList.push_back(result);
    PathsDone++;
}

std::vector<std::vector<double>> StatisticAllPaths::GetResultsSoFar() const
{
    vector<double> innerVector(ResultList);
    vector<vector<double> > Results(1, innerVector);
    Results[0] = ResultList;
    return Results;
}
```

In the second part I go through all the vectors and save the i element in the temp "output" vector, compare the values in output and save the result and then do the same. Looping through all the values in the thesePathGatherers. The first part runs fast but this one takes much longer and even fails to complete all together for high enough numberOfPaths. I added this part:

```
    if (i % 2500 == 0)
    {
        count += 1;
        std::cout << i << " paths done" << "\n";
    }
```

To debug and find that doing for example that doing the first 10^4 paths takes much longer if the total amount of paths is big, i.e. each individual path takes longer the more paths you do. Is there something wrong with the GetResultsSoFar() implementation/usage? That's the only thing I can imagine. Any help appreciated

Let me know if there is more I need to share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are answers here focusing on the excessive copying that happens in `GetResultsSoFar`, but none of them address the pointlessness of how you are calling this function:

```
std::vector<double> outcomes;
for (unsigned long j = 0; j < S_vect.size(); j++)
{
    outcomes.push_back(thesePathGatherers[j].GetResultsSoFar()[0][i]);
}
```

Here, you are gathering a single result value for every "path gatherer", but to do that you are copying each result list multiple times before extracting one value.  I think the first step of improving this is to avoid *any* copying of the `ResultList` because it's not needed.

Instead, how about returning a *const reference* to the results.  I'm going to also rename this function to avoid confusing it with your existing definition.  But call it whatever you like:

```
const std::vector<double>& StatisticAllPaths::GetResultList() const
{
    return ResultList;
}
```

Of course, the loop would then access the *ith* value as `thesePathGatherers[j].GetResultList()[i]`.  The critical difference here is no copying happened at all.

There's also a small optimization to do on `outcomes`.  Since you know exactly how many items you are going to push, you should reserve that memory up-front.

*i.e.*

```
std::vector<double> outcomes;
outcomes.reserve(S_vect.size());
for (unsigned long j = 0; j < S_vect.size(); j++)
{
    outcomes.push_back(thesePathGatherers[j].GetResultList()[i]);
}
```

If you want it to be even tidier, consider defining `double GetResult(size_t) const` that just returns a single result, and then calling `thesePathGatherers[j].GetResult(i)`.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late response but I've made your fix now creating a function that returns just one value by const reference like you said as so:

 `const double &StatisticAllPaths::GetOneValueFromResultsSoFar(unsigned long index) const
{
 return ResultList[index];
}`

And now the code runs probably 1000 times faster ( literally). Thank you very much for the help

Answer (score 1):

Well you are copying your ResultList vector 4 times, that can't help.

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> StatisticAllPaths::GetResultsSoFar() const
{
    vector<double> innerVector(ResultList); //first copy
    vector<vector<double> > Results(1, innerVector); //second copy
    Results[0] = ResultList;// third copy
    return Results;// return by value = fourth copy
}
```

You'd be better off passing your vector in by reference and filling it:

```
void StatisticAllPaths::GetResultsSoFar(std::vector<std::vector<double>> & result ) const
{
    result.clear(); //discard the current contents if any
    result.push_back(ResultList); //one copy
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I think the fourth copy could be disputed, given that pretty much any sane compiler would elide the copy through RVO.

Comment: @paddy Ah I see, it would perhaps be better to call GetResultsSoFar once outside the loop and store all the elements instead of calling it inside the loop every time to retrieve just one element?

Comment: I edited my comment to remove that, as I realized `GetResultsSoFar` was being called on a different object in each part of the loop.  However, since you are only ever obtaining one value, it does not make much sense to request a full vector-of-vectors per value.